# DSE Search 5.1. Solr 6 /sql endpoint

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise

Does anybody know whether DSE Search 5.1 has support for the **/sql** endpoint?. I was looking at the Solr setup and **/sql** endpoint seems to be missing beside the fact that Solr 6 includes this endpoint by default.

cheers

Comment: did you find answer for this?